# preg_match_all with php to get measurement values with unit

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am struggling to find a solution using preg_match_all to get from the following text only the value and the measurements untis ,  e.x. texts

```
MAN CAB HDMI TO HDMI M/M 18 cm SHIELDED 1.3V BLK 
MAN CAB HDMI TO HDMI M/M SHIELDED 1.3V BLK 18cm
MAN CAB HDMI TO HDMI M/M SHIELDED 1.3V BLK 5M
MAN CAB HDMI TO HDMI 5 M M/M SHIELDED 1.3V BLK 
MAN CAB HDMI TO HDMI M/M SHIELDED 1.3V BLK 5.0 m
MAN CAB HDMI TO HDMI M/M SHIELDED 1.3V BLK 5.2m
MAN CAB HDMI TO HDMI 5,2m M/M SHIELDED 1.3V BLK  
MAN CAB HDMI TO HDMI M/M 5,2 m SHIELDED 1.3V BLK
```

would like to get as results

```
18 cm,18cm,5M,5 M,5.00 M,5.0 mm,5.2m and 5,2m
```

Comment: How about `\d+[\.,]\d+\s*(V|cm|M|m)`

Comment: You have not outlined in your question why each value is chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9,.]+\s*(cm|m|mm)/mis", $string);
```

The `mis` flags make the regular expression case insensitive and allows matching over newlines.

Comment: yes is working but some fix would be needed I'll get  0 => '18 cm',
    1 => '18cm',
    2 => '5M',
    3 => '5 M',
    4 => '00 M',
    5 => '2m',
    6 => '5,2m',

Comment: You need to add `\.` to the character class.

Comment: The escape in `\.` is not actually required in character classes. `.` is enough, you don't have to escape it.

Comment: One faulty entry I encountered is string 
MAN CABLE HDMI/HDMI M/MV1.3,1.8m , the is no space between 1.3, 1.8m and as a result I'll get 1.3,1.8m , is there any trick here.. the text I preg_match is from an excel file , so I can not do anythign about this

Comment: I see, for that case, this could work: `"/([0-9,]+|[0-9.]+)\s*(cm|m|mm)/mis"`. Now it allows either `,` or `.` but not both.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9,\.]+\s?(cm|mm|m))/mis', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `[cm|mm|m]+` be `(cm|mm|m)`?

Comment: Nope, because the match is the whole pattern :)

Comment: @Ignas I mean `[cm|mm|m]+` is exactly the same as `[cm|]+` you're making a character class, not an or-list of options. Yours would also accept `5.5mmm` and `5.5|`.

Comment: Oh. My bad. +1 For you mate :)